# Prove $f(x)\equiv C$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$f(x)\in C[a,b]$.For any $g(x) \in C[a,b]$ ,which has the property that $\int_a^b g(x) dx=0$,$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx=0$.

Prove:$f(x)\equiv C$,$C$ is a constant.

I haven't any ideas yet.
I'm thinking about using the Fourier series,would it work?

Comment: No. For all g..

Comment: @DanielR For *any* $g(x)$.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry.

Comment: If $f$ were not constant try to split or partition $[a,b]$ according to the level sets of $f$ and use this (somehow?) to define a suitable $g$ with $\int_a^b g(x) dx=0$ for which $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx \not=0$. Perhaps the average value of $f$ on $[a,b]$ may be relevant.

Comment: What's $C[a,b]$, all functions continuous on $[a..b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\displaystyle I=\int_a^b f(x)dx$. Then $\displaystyle g=f-\frac{I}{b-a}$ is such that $\displaystyle \int_a^b g(x)dx=0$.

Hence $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=0$ and :

$$\int_a^b (f(x)-\frac{I}{b-a})^2dx=\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx-\frac{I}{b-a}\int_a^b g(x)dx=0$$
And we are done.

Comment: Well done!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Let assume that, without loss of generality, $[a,b]=[0,2\pi]$. It follows from your condition, the for any $n\ge 1$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\sin nx\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\cos nx\,dx = 0$$

What claims Fejer-Lebesgue theorem is that arithmetic mean of partial sums converges uniformly to a function:
$$\sigma_n(f,x) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}S_n(f,x) \rightrightarrows f(x)$$

Take as $g(x)$ (it is justified because of the firs two equations)
$$g(x) = \sigma_n(f,x) - \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx$$

Now, since
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\sigma_n(f,x) - \left(\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx\right)^2 = 0$$

and from the uniform convergence of $\sigma_n$, we get

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f^2(x)\,dx = \left(\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx\right)^2$$

Comment: $\int_0^1 \sin nx\,dx$ is not zero.

Comment: yea ), it must be $[0,2\pi]$, thanks

Comment: You could do the same using Stone-Weierstrass theorem and Legendre polynomials (on $[a,b]=[-1,1]$).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about using the Fourier series,is That right?

Without loss of generality，prove: in $[0,l]$，$f(x)\equiv C$.

let $g(x)=f(\mid x\mid)$

use Fourier series,we get：

\begin{aligned}
g(x)&={a_0 \over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos {n \pi x \over l}\\
a_0&=\int_{-l}^l g(x) dx \\
a_n&={1 \over l}\int_{-l}^l g(x)\cos {n \pi x \over l} dx\\
&={2 \over l}\int_0^l g(x)\cos {n \pi x \over l} dx
\end{aligned}

It's easy to get $a_n=0$,s.t $g(x)\equiv {a_0 \over 2}$